# Optimizing recursive XML build

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have some code that I wrote to build up an XML recursively, and it works very good as intended except one thing, that is not so generic.

The array is

```
string[] countries= string[]{ ..... }
```

My idea to have is following, if an array contains only 1 string than it should be:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef />
    <Value />
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

If there are more then one, than it should contain `<OR>`, but for the last string value should be in the same OR: so basically it would be something like that for 4 items:

```
<Where>
  <Or>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="Title" />
      <Value Type="Text">Canada</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Or>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Title" />
        <Value Type="Text">New Zealand</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Or>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Title" />
          <Value Type="Text">United States</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name="Title" />
          <Value Type="Text">Switzerland</Value>
        </Eq>
      </Or>
    </Or>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

Everything is nested.

Here is my code, it works great for the multi array but not for a single result:

```
private XElement Recursion(XElement parentElement, int counter)

    {
        if (counter == 0)
        { 
            return parentElement;
        }

        XElement orElement = new XElement("Or");
        XElement eqElement = new XElement("Eq");

        XElement fieldElement = new XElement("FieldRef");
        XAttribute nameAttribute = new XAttribute("Name", "Title");
        fieldElement.Add(nameAttribute);

        XElement valueElement = new XElement("Value", Countries[counter]);
        XAttribute typeAttribute = new XAttribute("Type", "Text");
        valueElement.Add(typeAttribute);

        eqElement.Add(fieldElement);
        eqElement.Add(valueElement);

        orElement.Add(eqElement);

        if (counter == 1)
        {
            eqElement = new XElement("Eq");
            valueElement = new XElement("Value", Countries[0]);
            valueElement.Add(typeAttribute);

            eqElement.Add(fieldElement);
            eqElement.Add(valueElement);

            orElement.Add(eqElement);
        }

         XElement lastOrElement = parentElement.Descendants("Or").FirstOrDefault(or => !or.Descendants("Or").Any());
        if (lastOrElement == null)
        {
            parentElement.Add(orElement);
        }
        else
        {
            lastOrElement.Add(orElement);
        }

        return Recursion(parentElement, --counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test when `counter` is 1 if this if the first time into the function.

Probably the simplest is to alter your `if (counter==1)` block to test if the passed parent element was empty (or did not contain any other `<OR>` elements (it not clear how first you call this function and when the `<where>` element is added.

Try something like:

```
if (counter == 1)
{
    if (!parentElement.Descendant("Or").Any())
    {
        //Single array case
        return eqElement;
    }

    // Not single array case, code as before....
    eqElement = new XElement("Eq");
    ...
```